# Diferença entre Vast x VPAID

Tags: google, plugin, publicidade

Estou tentando ver mas não consegui entender qual seria a diferença entre esses dois Vast x VPAID eu comprei um plugin para utilizar o DFP do google com o Vast, mas qual seria a diferença dele para o VPAID?

Answer (score 2):

**VAST**

[VAST](https://www.iab.com/guidelines/digital-video-ad-serving-template-vast-3-0/) (*The Video Ad Serving Template*): Uma especificação universal desenvolvida pelo [IAB](https://www.iab.com/our-story/) (*Interactive Advertising Bureau*) para veicular anúncios em vídeo.

O VAST é como um "script" para o anúncio, o que ele está realmente fazendo é dar instruções consistentes ao seu player de vídeo sobre como lidar com um anúncio. Ele informa ao seu player de vídeo o que o anúncio deve fazer - como ele deve aparecer no player, quanto tempo ele deve exibir, se ele é ou não ignorável, onde encontrar o anúncio (ou seja, o servidor de anúncios).

**VPAID**

[VPAID](https://www.iab.com/guidelines/digital-video-player-ad-interface-definition-vpaid-2-0/) (*The Video Player-Ad Interface Definition*): Uma especificação universal desenvolvida pelo IAB para interação entre blocos de anúncios e reprodutores de vídeo focada em "permitir uma experiência interativa rica em anúncios in-stream".

O VPAID adiciona a interatividade. Conforme indicado no site do IAB, o VAST suporta apenas formatos de anúncios em vídeo *in-stream*. Com ele é permitido aos players de vídeo que sejam compatíveis exibam anúncios multimídia interativos.O VPAID baseia-se no VAST para permitir experiências de anúncios avançadas e uma análise avançada do visualizador.

Veja como fazer a [implementação do servidor de anúncios para players de anúncios compatíveis com VAST / VPAID](https://support.google.com/adxseller/answer/3388006?hl=pt-BR)

Referência: [Difference between VPAID and VAST](http://www.knowonlineadvertising.com/difference-between/difference-between-vpaid-and-vast/)